# Settings must be of the form "name=value" in Eventhub client creation

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azureservicebus

An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Settings must be of the form "name=value".

while creating eventProcessorHost in EventHub

```
 var eventProcessorHost = new EventProcessorHost(
                EhEntityPath,
                EventHubConsumerGroup.DefaultGroupName,
                EhConnectionString,
                StorageConnectionString,
                StorageContainerName);
```

Sample values

```
 string EhConnectionString = "Endpoint=sb://namespacename-ns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=receivepolicy;SharedAccessKey=v7IHIH+jB3+H2UMxEOr9kHYfhwj1Q=;EntityPath=sampleeventhub";
 string EhEntityPath = "sampleeventhub";
 string StorageContainerName = "containername"; //I have created in blob and type as container
 string StorageAccountName = "storegenameinazure";
 string StorageAccountKey = "GHasmRRJgI5s123ziDlfOKQ7IBrO23EvHpk++TV0L2hU2erdI7PyY+gtvUop67lIU0+zQsM09sQ==";

  static readonly string StorageConnectionString = string.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1}", StorageAccountName, StorageAccountKey);
```

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Any concerns, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I leverage [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.EventProcessorHost](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.EventProcessorHost/) version (2.2.10) to test this issue.

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll** but was not handled in user code. Additional information: **Settings must be of the form "name=value"**.

Based on your code, I assumed that you have not built your `EventProcessorHost` constructor correctly, the constructor you used looks like this:

[image]

At this point, the parameter `StorageContainerName` you passed would be treated as `storageConnectionString` parameter, then you got the above error.

In summary, please build your `EventProcessorHost` with the correct constructor. Here are some tutorials you could refer to them ([event-processor-host-best-practices](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servicebus/2015/01/16/event-processor-host-best-practices-part-1/) and [azure-event-hubs-processing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2015/02/24/scaling-azure-event-hubs-processing-with-worker-roles/)).